# Where does this identity come from (natural parametrization)

Tags: curves, parametrization

Reading *Analytical Mechanics* by Fasano and Marmi, I bumped into this identity with natural parametrization.

[image: Natural parametrization]

Where does the identity
\begin{equation}
s=\int_0^s\left|\frac{d\boldsymbol{x}}{d\sigma}\right|d\sigma
\end{equation}
come from?

Comment: Differentiate both sides of the equation $s=\int_0^s \left|\frac{dx}{dt}dt\right|$ with respect to $s$

Comment: The previous equation $s=\int_0^s|\frac{dx}{dt}|dt$ comes from a reparametrisation wrt $s$: $x(t)=\tilde x \circ s(t)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\dot x(t) = \dot{\tilde x}(s(t)) s'(t)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\dot x(t)dt= \dot{\tilde x}(s) ds$ and then take abolsute value and  integrate both sides

Answer (score 0):

In the complex plane we can say that a differential length $ds$ is given by

$$ds = |dz| =\bigg| \frac{dz}{du}\bigg| du =|\dot z|du$$

and thus the arc length between two parametric points, say $u_{1,2}$ is thus

$$s=\int_{u_1}^{u_2}|\dot z|du$$